# Width and Height 100percent is not working

Tags: html, css

Lets say i have two divs

```
<div class="1">
    <div class="2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Div 1 have this style

```
width: calc(100% - 22rem);
min-height: calc(100% - 7.75rem);
```

How can i set div 2 to same size as div1?
Because `width:100%` and `height:100%` wont work

Comment: use flex box or position absolute

Comment: use `min-width` and `min-height` it will works

Comment: Thanks display flex with min height and min width work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: absolute;
```

works fine as mentioned by [Barbu Barbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829174/barbu-barbu)

Here's a fiddle for visualization

https://jsfiddle.net/rvzqsgc1/3/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 22rem);
  min-height: calc(100% - 7.75rem);
  background-color: white;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, It will work for you.

```css
  body { 
      background: black
    }
    
    .one {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #FFF;
      width: calc(100% - 22rem);
      min-height: calc(100% - 7.75rem);
    }
    .two {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: orange;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="one">
        <div class="two">
        </div>
    </div>
```